# PHP code how to use if else

Tags: php

My question is if Destination in Tokyo Discount 200 per Travelers who stays at least 5 nights.

```
    if($destination == "Barcelona")
    {
    $airFare = 875;
    $perNight = 85;
    }

    else if($destination == "Cairo")
    {
    $airFare = 950;
    $perNight = 98;
    }

    else if($destination == "Rome")
    {
    $airFare = 875;
    $perNight = 110;
    }

    else if($destination == "Santiago")
    {
    $airFare = 820;
    $perNight = 85;
    }

    elseif($destination == "Tokyo")
    {
    $airFare = 1575;
    $perNight = 240;        
    }


    $tickets = $numTravelers * $airFare;
    $hotel = $numTravelers * $numNights * $perNight;
    $totalCost = $tickets + $hotel;
```

*I cannot change any code here just need to add it to get $200 discount who is going to Tokyo and staying 5 nights! 
If I input 1 passenger for 5 nights to Tokyo the value must be $2575.

Also, I have to use Nested If or Compound Boolean Expression for this!
Thank you for all your helps!

This is my code how to I add up the question to get 200 discount in this code? Destination in Tokyo, At least saying 5 nights per travelers get 200 discount.

Comment: Where is your variable for duration of stay?

Comment: Need more details about the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 $subtotal=0;

elseif($destination == "Tokyo")
    {
    $airFare = 1575;
    $perNight = 240; 
      if($numNights >= 5){
        $subtotal= ($perNight*numNights)-200;
      }else{
        $subtotal= ($perNight*numNights)-200;
      }       
    }

$tickets = $numTravelers * $airFare;
    $hotel = $numTravelers * $numNights * $perNight;
```

**change to:**

```
$hotel = $numTravelers * $subtotal;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but your code does not work. Thanks

Comment: Okay, Can you explain it more?

Comment: Yes there is no $subtotal in my code. How do I get the subtotal from? I need to add a code to get 200 discount for who stays in Tokyo for at least 5 nights per passenger.

Comment: you can define a variable that will hold total before or after discount applied.

Comment: if their condition meets with then the total will different.

Comment: Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I added up more detail below. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You should add another `IF` statement inside the code for Tokyo. Now, assuming you have declared the `$discount = 200` and the `$nights` variables. Use this:

```
elseif($destination == "Tokyo")
    {
    $airFare = 1575;
    $perNight = 240;
if($nights >= 5){
    $total = ($airFare + $perNight) - $discount;   
    }
    }
```

Comment: Then provide more details if you need assistance

Comment: Thank you for your help but It does not work! I added up more detail for this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I try to modify your code as minimal as possible, and here it is:
EDITED to only stay 5 nights in Tokyo will get one time $200 discount

```
        if($destination == "Barcelona")
        {
            $airFare = 875;
            $perNight = 85;
        }

        else if($destination == "Cairo")
        {
            $airFare = 950;
            $perNight = 98;
        }

        else if($destination == "Rome")
        {
            $airFare = 875;
            $perNight = 110;
        }

        else if($destination == "Santiago")
        {
            $airFare = 820;
            $perNight = 85;
        }

        elseif($destination == "Tokyo")
        {
            $airFare = 1575;
            $perNight = 240;        
        }

        $discount = ($destination == "Tokyo" && $numNight == 5)? 200 : 0; // condition is here
        $tickets = $numTravelers * $airFare;
        $hotel = $numTravelers * $numNights * $perNight;
        $totalCost = $tickets + $hotel - $discount;
    ?>
```

This is what I would suggest to you. You may find it very different:

Create a function rather then a lengthy elseif(s). Switch case may also be considered but I have found simply using array is more convenient to handle. Hope that helps

```
<?php
function getCost($destination, $numTravelers, $numNights) {

    // organize them in an array format
    $prices["Barcelona"] = ['airfare' => 875, 'perNight' => 85, 'discount' => 0];
    $prices["Cairo"] = ['airfare' => 950, 'perNight' => 98, 'discount' => 0];
    $prices["Rome"] = ['airfare' => 875, 'perNight' => 110, 'discount' => 0];
    $prices["Tokyo"] = ['airfare' => 875, 'perNight' => 110, 'discount' => 200];    

    $min = 5; // minimum stay for discount

    // just get the value by providing the key (destination name)
    $tickets = $prices[$destination]['airfare'] * $numTravelers;
    $hotel = $numTravelers * $numNights * $prices[$destination]['perNight'];
    $total =  ($numNights = $min) ? $tickets + $hotel - $prices[$destination]['discount'] : $tickets + $hotel;
    // just for viewing the output
    echo 'Travel to ' . $destination . ' for ' . $numTravelers . ' people for ' . $numNights . ' nights cost: ' . $total . '<br>';
    return $total;
}

$cost1 = getCost('Tokyo', 3, 4);

$cost2 = getCost('Tokyo', 3, 5);
?>
```

OUTPUT

Travel to Tokyo for 3 people for 4 nights cost: 3945

Travel to Tokyo for 3 people for 5 nights cost: 4075

Comment: I cannot use your code which is not what I want. Sorry! I must use Nested If or Compound Boolean Expression.

Comment: Thank you mike! Your second code works if I input 5 nights I get 200 discount but there is a problem. If I input greater than 5 like 6 or 7, I don't get 200 discount. Why is that? It must get 200 discount if the number is greater than 5.

Comment: You want a one time discount of 200, or you want to give $200 for every exceeding night? So night 5 + night 6 + night 7..$total 600? Or still $200

Comment: I mean if I input 6 nights in Tokyo, there is no 200 discount.

Comment: So just change it from $numNight >= 5 to $numNight = 5 (ANSWER UPDATED)

Comment: I did $numNight == 5 but still does not get 200 discount if I input higher than number 5.

Comment: I am confused. Let me ask again, if someone stays over 7 nights, they get $200, right? if Yes, my original answer should work as I tested.

Comment: @BoramLamppa: sorry, you can't do that. Questions, together with their answers, are here for future visitors, and changing any of those parts as radically as you did is a form of vandalism. If you have a new question, then do follow the procedure to for a new post, including doing your research, etc.